# How to stop refreshing page after ajax call (only happening while saving a image)?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

After saving an image in controller, the page is getting reload automatically after ajax success. If image is not available, there is no issue. how to stop reloading the page?

- Method

  ```
   if (desktopImageUpload != null)
    {

        var file = desktopImageUpload;
        var fileFormat = Path.GetFileName(file.ContentType);
        var fileName = "promo-" + fileID + "-desktop." + fileFormat;

        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/SocialMediaPromotions"), fileName);
              file.SaveAs(path);               

     }
  ```
- ajax

  ```
     $.ajax({

              type: 'POST',
              dataType: 'JSON',
              url: '/Admin/RecordSocialMediaPromotions',
              data: formData,
              contentType: false,
              processData: false,
              success: function (response) {

                  if (response.type == "Success") {
                      swal("Hooray", "Promotion Recorded Successfully", "success");
                      $('#preLoader').hide();
                      $("#dealSaveBtn").prop("disabled", true);

                  } else {
                      swal("Boooo", response.msg, "error");
                      $('#preLoader').hide();
                  }
              },
              error: function (response) {
                  swal("Boooo", "Promotion was not recorded", "error");
                  $('#preLoader').hide();
              }

        });
  ```

Comment: Check once upload button click if  your are using  button type is not be submit 
<button input type="button">

Comment: If I use type as button the bootstrapvalidator won't work.

Comment: <button> click is always work there is no restriction in JQuery or Bootstrap
more documentation on https://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: I tried, for bootstrapvalidator only validation works in <button input type="submit">

Answer (score 0):

If your "button" is a `button` element, make sure you explicity set the `type` attribute, otherwise the WebForm will treat it as submit by default.

```
<button id="dealSaveBtn" type="button">Go</button>
```

If it's an `input` element, try below :

```
    e.preventDefault();
```

Read more: [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)

Comment: If I use type as button the bootstrapvalidator won't work.